# Unity AVProVideo Plugin causing movement jitter and overall frame drops

Tags: unity-game-engine, video

I'm using this plugin from the asset store to record the screen.
[Asset store link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/avpro-video-56355)

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen frame drops while using this plugin.

We have another plugin that shows rendering frame drops. This is what it looks like when it's not capturing.

[image: not capturing]

And looks like this when it is capturing causing our product to stutter.

[image: capturing]

I'm looking for any ideas on trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the CaptureFromScreen component instead of the CaptureFromCamera component. Now no more frame drops